# ESlinter asking on useEffect a dep

Tags: use-effect, typescript-eslint

I have this useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (allValidated) {
    setState({
      ...state,
      buttonDisabled: false
    });
  } else {
    setState({
      ...state,
      buttonDisabled: true
    });
  }
}, [allValidated, validation]); // HERE is the warning:
```

`React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'state'. Either include it or remove the dependency array. You can also do a functional update 'setState(s => ...)' if you only need 'state' in the 'setState' call`

But if I add `state` to the deps arrays the Component enters in a loop.

`state` is defined as:

```
const [state, setState] = useState(defaultState);
```

Where `defaultState` is this object, and can be updated in different parts:

```
const defaultState = {
  amplifyError: false,
  buttonDisabled: true,
  errors: defaultError,
  password: '',
  show: false,
  username: '',
  validation: defaultValidation
};
```

I don't want to use a `@ts-ignore` because I think that it could be resolved, and not ignored. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the warning, you can also do a functional update `setState(s => ...)`. For example, your first setState would look like this:

```js
setState(s => {
    ...s,
    buttonDisabled: false
});
```

and so forth for the second one !